# Integrating $f_n(x)$, where $f_n(x)=-x\cdot f'_{n-1}(x)$. What did I do wrong?

Tags: integration

I wondered what would happen if I integrated a function defined in terms of it's derivative and after some puzzling, this is what I got:

Define $f_n(x)=-x\cdot f_{n-1}'(x)$. Now:
$$I=\int f_n(x)\,dx$$
We take $u=f_n(x)\implies\,du=f_n'(x)\,dx$ and $\,dv=\,d\implies v=x$, so:
$$I=x\cdot f_n(x)-\int x\cdot f_n'(x)\,dx=x\cdot f_n(x)+\int f_{n+1}(x)\,dx$$
which would mean:
$$\int f_n(x)\,dx=x\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}f_k(x)+C$$

---

However, the above result doesn't seem correct. Take for instance $f_n(x)=(n-1)!(\log x)^{-n}$.

It satisfies $f_n(x)=-x\cdot f'_{n-1}(x)$, but when I use try my little trick, I get:
$$\int(\log x)^{-1}\,dx=\int f_1(x)\,dx=x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(k-1)!}{(\log x)^k}+C$$
which isn't correct.

Question: What did I do wrong? I really have no idea. I don't use integration often, so it could be something realy obvious (I hope not).

Comment: You forgot the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int f_{n+1}\,dx$ term, "so to say". But besides that the argument is indeed flawless for finite sums. I.e you indeed get:
$$\int f_n\, dx=x\sum_{k=n}^N f_k +\int f_{N+1}\, dx+C, \text{ for any }N\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: You didn't take convergence into account. **If** the series $\sum_{k = n}^{\infty} f_k(x)$ converges nicely, then it works. If it doesn't, you can only ever do finitely many such steps.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I now know what was wrong.